# How to use pivot to generate a single-row matrix?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to pivot the following two-column dataframe to one-row one (long to wide).

```
+--------+-----+
|   udate|   cc|
+--------+-----+
|20090622|  458|
|20090624|31068|
|20090626|  151|
|20090629|  148|
|20090914|  453|
+--------+-----+
```

I need it in this format:

```
+--------+------------+----------+----------+
|   udate|   20090622 | 20090624 | 20090626 |
+--------+------------+----------+----------+
|     cc |         458|    31068 |      151 |etc
```

I ran this:

```
result_df.groupBy($"udate").pivot("udate").agg(max($"cc")).show()
```

but ended up with a matrix of all rows transposed to all columns:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---
|   udate|20090622|20090624|20090626|20090629|20090703|200
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---
|20090622|     458|    null|    null|    null|    null|   
|20090624|    null|   31068|    null|    null|    null|   
|20090626|    null|    null|     151|    null|    null|   
|20090629|    null|    null|    null|     148|    null|   
|20090703|    null|    null|    null|    null|     362|   
|20090704|    null|    null|    null|    null|    null|   
|20090715|    null|    null|    null|    null|    null|   
|20090718|    null|    null|    null|    null|    null|   
|20090721|    null|    null|    null|    null|    null|   
|20090722|    null|    null|    null|    null|    null|
```

I expected that pivoting a one-column dataset should result in a one-row pivoted dataset.

How can I modify the pivot command so that the result set is pivoted to one row?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** In Spark 2.4.0 it simply boils down to using `groupBy` alone.

```
val solution = d.groupBy().pivot("udate").agg(first("cc"))
scala> solution.show
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|20090622|20090624|20090626|20090629|20090914|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     458|   31068|     151|     148|     453|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

If you really need the first column with the names just use `withColumn` and you're done.

```
val betterSolution = solution.select(lit("cc") as "udate", $"*")
scala> betterSolution.show
+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|udate|20090622|20090624|20090626|20090629|20090914|
+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   cc|     458|   31068|     151|     148|     453|
+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```